# std::invoke and a complex function pointer to class member

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, pointer-to-member

I am experimenting with `std::invoke`. I find rather straightforward to use a function pointer to a class member function, the object and any arguments. What I struggle to understand is how to use the following with `std::invoke`

```
    QTextEdit* textEdit ....
    int sz = textEdit->text().size();
```

The following doesn't work

```
    int sz = std::invoke(&QTextEdit::text::size, textEdit);
    // Error : text is not a class, namespace or enumeration
```

What I need to access is `int QString::size()` since `QTextEdit::text` returns `QString`. What syntax can overcome this problem?

Comment: Pointers to member functions cannot "nest", you'll have to use a lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling a function on the returned value of the `text()` method. This means your scope will not work as `size()` is not a part of your class, but rather a method on the returned type. As an example, if the return type is `std::string`, you should be able to do the following:

```
// Calling "size()" on the returned value
int sz = std::invoke(&QTextEdit::text, textEdit).size();
// Calling "text" and "size" via "std::invoke"
int sz = std::invoke(&std::string::size, std::invoke(&QTextEdit::text, textEdit));
```

Comment: This worked! The following compiles: `if (std::invoke(&QString::size, std::invoke(&QLineEdit::text, lineWordEdit.data())) == 1)`

Comment: I could also do this to make it even more cryptic and error - prone : 

    `auto fptr = std::invoke(&QLineEdit::text, lineWordEdit.data());` 
    `if (std::invoke(&decltype(fptr)::size, fptr) == 1) { /**/ }`

Comment: hmm, it's not exactly a function pointer being returned from the `text()` method, but yes that definitely looks unnecessarily complex

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's a plain `QString`, nothing more. Good point.